# NetTiers 2.3 generation failing

Tags: c#, .net, codesmith, .nettiers

I have a .nettiers 2.3 template that I have been generating from a SQL Server 2008 database which has been working for some time.

In the last few days, however, the generation has been failing with the output saying there is 1 Error/Warning, but I am unable to find what the error or warning actually is.

The solution is generates compiles fine, all of the tables have primary keys and nothing has changed in the template file or project file since it was working, apart from adding some new tables to the table list.

Is there a location that the .nettiers generation is saving a log file to, or can I increase the logging level in the template. I have already put the verbose flag in NetTiers.cst to true but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, somehow the "Generate Web Security" flag was set to True, which, until now, hadn't been causing any problems. For some reason (perhaps updating Codesmith, database etc) this started failing.

Since I'm not using the web security, turning this off allowed NetTiers to build properly.

Comment: thanks for following up. In the future, I'd recommend posting to the .netTiers forums as it is checked on a daily basis: http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16.aspx